# Running Rserve as service

Tags: r

I am currently working on one project which uses R to do a very sophisticated calculation, it sets up to be called by ASP.NET web application. It uses RServe as the interface to R and needs to use ROracle and DBI libraries too.

Now the problem is every time when the server restarts, I have to sign in to the server to launch the Rserve command manually, the question is: is there any way to automatically run RServe every time when server restarts. I am running it on windows.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

As the public documentation of Rserve says, you can start Rserve from a shell script.

Just create a script that executes the following command:

```
echo 'library(Rserve);Rserve(FALSE,args="--no-save --slave --RS-conf <your_own_path>/rserve.conf")'|<R_bin_path>/R --no-save --slave
```

For instance, in my MacOS computer I can start Rserve executing this line:

```
/bin/sh -c "echo 'library(Rserve);Rserve(FALSE,args=\"--slave\")'|/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/bin/exec/R --no-save --slave"
```

This command outputs something like this:

```
Starting Rserve:
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rserve/libs//Rserve --slave 

Rserv started in daemon mode.
```

You can create a shell script (or windows script) and tell the OS to execute this script during the startup process.